# Voltage output on thyratron gas tube relaxation oscillator VCO?

Tags: vintage, tube, thyratron

I know that thyratron gas tubes can be used to make a sawtooth like relaxation oscillator:

[image: thyratron relaxation oscillator]

My question is for a modification of this same circuit that makes it act like a voltage controlled oscillator (VCO.)

Does the output voltage vary based the output frequency or should it stay the same no matter what the frequency is? I have suspicions it does change based on the frequency, but with what this circuit was used for I am sure they would have wanted the same output voltage no matter if the frequency changes. I am not even sure that you would consider this circuit to be a VCO. The schematics no where say it is a VCO, except that I know that changing the negative voltage at the grid does change the frequency output.

[image: thyratron relaxation oscillator VCO?]

I know how it works.  If you put any negative voltage on the grid of the thyratron that will change the charge rate of the capacitor and will output the same waveform but at different frequencies based on the negative voltage at the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The charge rate on the capacitor is not changed; it acts as an integrator with periodic reset.  The reset voltage, and therefore rate, is determined by the thyratron's threshold voltage, which depends on grid voltage.  It is a VCO, but not a good one.

Note the amplitude is fairly stable in the region pictured in the waveform, but this is a poor region to operate in as the frequency varies rapidly with voltage, including due to internal noise in the tube itself: the tone is not very pure / stable.

Better is to vary the current into the capacitor, which can be done with a voltage-to-current converter (transconductance amplifier), so the amplitude stays more consistent.  This is how most multivibrator type VCOs work.  And arguably, the DSP equivalent implementation, the DDS (direct digital synthesis).

Comment: but though if you change the voltage on the grid does that change the output voltage as well?

Comment: That's what I mean by "reset voltage": the voltage at which it turns on, resetting the voltage on the capacitor.